# Am I using the isNAN function in JavasScript correctly here?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've got a form where the user inputs 3 values, which are then calculated. The outputs are displayed again within the form in some "readonly" output boxes. For each input, I want to validate if they are a number, if not, instead of the form showing "NaN" I want to display an error saying, "Please enter a number" (or something like that). Below is the code I am using, which is executed "onkeyup":

```
function checkforNumber() 
{
    if (isNaN(sInput || dInput || pInput) == true) {
        alert("You entered an invalid character. Please reset the form.");
    }
    else {
        return(false);
    }
}
```

Am I using this function incorrectly? Is there something wrong with the syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (isNaN(sInput) || isNaN(dInput) || isNaN(pInput)) {
    alert("You entered an invalid character. Please reset the form.");
}
```

also make sure that those 3 variables `sInput`, `dInput` and `pInput` are not strings but were obtained by using [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) or [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) methods.

```
var sInput = parseFloat(document.getElementById('sinput').value);
var dInput = parseFloat(document.getElementById('dinput').value);
var pInput = parseFloat(document.getElementById('pinput').value);
```

Comment: Great thanks for your help, also the number are parseFloat but thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isNaN(sInput) || isNaN(dInput) || isNaN(pInput))
```

This is what I think you intended. You need to pass each value you want to test in to the `isNaN` function one at a time. Also note that you don't need the `== true` part, because `isNaN` returns `true` or `false` so the condition will evaluate to the return value.